# How to convert list values into Key, value format?

Tags: scala

## Input

```
List(List(1, 2, 3, 4),List(5, 6, 6, 8),List(2,4,5,0))
```

### expected output

```
(1: 2)

(5: 6)

(2: 4)
```

I tried with the below code

```
 val res = input.map(x => println(x(0)+ " "+x(1)+" "+x(2)+" " +x(3)))
```

its getting like this

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 6 8
2 4 5 0
```

Comment: Why do you expect to get anything different, there are neither `':'` nor `','` in your code.

Comment: Do you want to print the contents in a string of some specific format, or do you actually want to create a `Map` of keys and values?

Comment: I want to create map of Key and values

Comment: What should happen if a sub-list is empty or contains only one element? What should happen if two different sub-lists both start with an element of the same value? i.e. `List(List(7,8),List(7,9))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow this approach

```
val input = List(List(1, 2, 3, 4),List(5, 6, 6, 8),List(2,4,5,0))

val res0 = input.map(x => x match
{case y :: ys => (y -> ys) }
).toMap


val res1 = res0.foreach{x => println(x._1 + ": " + x._2.mkString(","))}
```

res1 will print an output like

```
1: 2,3,4
5: 6,6,8
2: 4,5,0
res1: Unit = ()
```

Please let me know if this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine pattern marching and string interpolation:

```
val result = input.map {
    case key :: values => s"$key: ${values.mkString(",")}"
}.mkString("\n")

println(result)
```

- `case key :: values` matches the first element of the list (your key) and the rest of elements in the list (your values).
- `mkString(separator)` joins the elements of the list into a string using the given separator.